# Accessing GPU memory content

Tags: memory, gpu, picamera

I'm currently working with advanced picamera parameters. 
A new functionnality to come is the "lens shading correction", a RGGB array that modify the image generated by the camera in order to compensate darks halos and color shifting.

The generation of this array is quite complicated (need a photography lab), so some users just want to modify the original table.
Problem, the original table was never publicated ...

Playing with the `sudo vcdbg reloc` command, I was able to locate the GPU memory blocks that (seems to) contain these precious values :

```
[  62] 0x375af2e0: used  25K (refcount 1 lock count 0, size    25100, align    4, data 0x375af300, d0rual) 'ls table 4'
[  37] 0x375b5540: used  25K (refcount 1 lock count 0, size    25100, align    4, data 0x375b5560, d0rual) 'ls table 3'
[  96] 0x375bb7a0: used  25K (refcount 1 lock count 0, size    25100, align    4, data 0x375bb7c0, d0rual) 'ls table 2'
[  71] 0x375c1a00: used  25K (refcount 1 lock count 0, size    25100, align    4, data 0x375c1a20, d0rual) 'ls table 1'
[  34] 0x375c7c60: used  25K (refcount 1 lock count 0, size    25100, align    4, data 0x375c7c80, d0rual) 'ls table 0'
[  25] 0x37647bc0: used  25K (refcount 1 lock count 0, size    25100, align    4, data 0x37647be0, d0rual) 'ls table isp'
[  55] 0x3764de20: used  25K (refcount 1 lock count 0, size    25100, align    4, data 0x3764de40, d0rual) 'ls table tx1'
[  28] 0x37654080: used  25K (refcount 1 lock count 0, size    25100, align    4, data 0x376540a0, d0rual) 'ls table tx0'
[  15] 0x3765a2e0: used  25K (refcount 1 lock count 0, size    25100, align    4, data 0x3765a300, d0rual) 'ls table 1'
[  19] 0x37660540: used  25K (refcount 1 lock count 0, size    25100, align    4, data 0x37660560, d0rual) 'ls table 0'
```

Is there a way to access these memory adresses, or to dump the whole GPU memory to a file ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

The answer was in the question ^^

The `vcdbg` program has a `dump` command, and shoud be called like this :

`vcdbg dump addr len`

Thank you everyone :)